# android: adapter for textview

Tags: android

I have multiple TextViews .  When I click on the TextView I would like to  grab the associated object. I know there are ListAdapters for list views and other collection type views.  Is there a way to dynamically associate a custom object with a TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can attach. Here are apis from the `View` since `TextView` is extended from `View` you can use them.

```
setTag(Object tag)
setTag(int key, Object tag)
```

How to use:

```
class YourCustomData {
  public int data;
}

// in your onCreate
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
tv.setTag(new YourCustomData());
```

-

```
// say somewhere you have a handler/listener for text view
// Note: you have to write the code to get the textview
YourCustomData ycd = (YourCustomData)tv.getTag();
```

Android Developers Reference:

- [setTag(java.lang.Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `HashMap<View, Object>`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html